# How to maintain nodes at the same level in dagre-d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dagre-d3

I have created a simple flow chart using dagreD3, please check the example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/26z9chto/)

I have few set of nodes

```
  graph.setNode('a', {label: 'a', height: 20, width: 40})
  graph.setNode('b', {label: 'b', height: 20, width: 40})
  graph.setNode('c', {label: 'c', height: 20, width: 40})
  graph.setNode('d', {label: 'd', height: 20, width: 40})
  graph.setNode('e', {label: 'e', height: 20, width: 40})
  graph.setNode('f', {label: 'f', height: 20, width: 40})
  graph.setNode('main', {label: 'Main', heihgt: 100})
```

Which has edges like this

```
  graph.setEdge('a', 'c')
  graph.setEdge('b', 'c')
  graph.setEdge('c', 'main')
  graph.setEdge('d', 'e')
  graph.setEdge('e', 'main')
  graph.setEdge('f', 'main')
  // graph.setEdge('main', 'e')
```

The problem here is, there is last edge `graph.setEdge('main', 'e')`, as **main** is parent of e, the **e** node comes below the **main** node.

What i am expecting is when i try to set a edge from `main to e` it should maintain the same level and draw a line from `main to e`. I just wanted to maintain **main** at last level of flow chart. Is there any possible way to maintain **main** at the same level and all remaining nodes should be on top of the **main**?

In the above link please uncomment this line `graph.setEdge('main', 'e')` and see how the graph is changing.